# Cambiar la ruta de carga de imagenes en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, storage

Buenas tengo una APP web alojada en un servidor con una IP y el backend esta en el mismo servidor pero en otra IP, y los registros se están insertando desde la app externa a la BD de la web.
El problema es que cuando guardo un registro que contiene un campo `foto` me guarda una URL. `/storage/photos/1/Chica calculando.jpg`.

El problema que cuando la app web inserto la imagen con `{{ asset("{$item->foto}") }}` busca en la IP actual, pero el archivo está en otro proyecto con otra IP.

Lo he planteado mal?

Mi idea es manejar dos web desde un mismo backend, pero la información que pertenece a esa web esta con una base de datos propia.

Es mejor, crearlo todo en una misma BD y a través de una API consumir por ejemplo las noticias del blog? Pero creo que tambien sucederia lo de las fotos no? al guardar esa url siempre buscara la ip incorrecta.

No se si me explico, pero al final es desde un mismo backend gestionar las iteraciones de dos webs.

A las iteraciones que llevan un foto puedo añadirle la ip al asset, el problema es que uso un editor de texto que se llama tinyMCe y ahí si que no puedo alterar la ip.

Comment: Si el problema es solo la funcion **asset** podrias usar https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.html#method_assetFrom y meter la ip de tu backend en el env para no hardcodearlo en tu app. y usar https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#introduction para leerlo y pasarlo a tus vistas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que estás utilizando el storage y ambos servicios están en el mismo servidor.

Es más fácil que crees una carpeta en la que ambas aplicaciones tengan acceso.

Ejemplo `/usr/app/storage`.

Importante dar permisos de escritura y lectura a dicha carpeta.

`sudo chmod -R 666 /usr/app/storage`

Habría que generar un enlace simbólico en la aplicación que mostrara las imágenes, si es necesario en ambas, puedes hacerlo. ¿Porqué el enlace simbólico?, para poder exponer las imágenes compartidas, sobre la carpeta `public` de nuestro proyecto, de está forma podremos acceder desde `http://misitio.io/storage/imagen.jpg`

```
ln -s /usr/app/storage /var/www/proyecto2/public/storage
```

Solo debes reconfigurar el storage local y público.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

`config/filesystem.php`

```
...
// Ambas aplicaciones llevan está configuración
'shared' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => '/usr/app/storage',
        ],
// Esta es necesario para que los ficheros se encuentren públicos
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => '/usr/app/storage',
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
...
```

Para subir ficheros harías lo siguiente.

`$request->file('my_file')->store('shared');`

Para Obtener la ruta de los ficheros

`$path = asset('storage/my_file.png');`

Comment: Hola @Hammerffall BK puedes lucidar un poco mis dudas? Donde iria esa carpeta? son dos proyectos de Laravel distintos y uno esta en un dominio y otro en una IP. No se si puedes extender un poco más como y donde tengo que crear esa carpeta y como doy acceso, gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: La carpeta puede ir en la ubicación que tu decidas. `/usr/app/storage` es un ejemplo

Comment: Pero los dos proyectos tienen una carpeta `/public/storage` de ahí mi duda, la web que tengo un ip, si tiene imagenes pero para otra no, como conecto la segunda a la primera, ya que los dos son proyectos de laravel independientes? @Hammerffall BK

Comment: Si, estás manejando dos proyectos laravel en un mismo servidor. Uno de ellos sube imagenes a su `public/storage`, y otro proyecto es el que trata de incrustarlo en el html(pero no lo tiene en su `public/storage`). Lo que se busca es básicamente compartir esas imagenes(ya que están en el mismo servidor). Hay que modificar las rutas de el sistema de ficheros, para  que pueda apuntar a esa carpeta compartida.

Comment: Si eso lo entiendo @Hammerffall BK pero lo que no entiendo es, el proyecto que sube las imagenes puedo dejar la ruta que tiene que es `storage/app/public/photos` pero como enlazo el otro proyecto por ruta con este? en la ruta tengo que salir del proyecto para entrar en el otro? es lo único que no entiendo

Comment: Si puede, pero `storage/app/public/photos` está en la carpeta de un solo proyecto. Puedes enlazar el fichero al segundo proyecto en `public/storage/`, si llegas a remover el primer proyecto del servidor y borras todo, claramente el segundo proyecto ya no tendría acceso a esas imágenes. Yo propuse que dado que están en el mismo servidor, sería buena idea que puedan compartir un fichero.

Comment: Hola @Hammerffall BK por fin lo he entendido, lo siento pero hasta que no comprendo no se como proceder. Muchas gracias y siento que la recompensa ya no sean 100 al pasar el tiempo. Gracias!

Comment: Lo importante es que lo hayas resuelto.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo,primeramente poner todo en el public, pero un lugar de guardar solo el nombre de la imagen, tendrias que guardar toda la `url` es decir en lugar de

`/storage/photos/1/Chica calculando.jpg`

deberia ser

`{dominio}/storage/photos/1/Chica calculando.jpg`

u otra alternativa es poner el `dominio` como variable

por ejemplo, puedes declaralo en el `.env : IMAGES_URL=http://superhost.imagenes.com`

```
<img src="{{ env('IMAGES_URL').'/'.$item->foto }}" />
```

Si las web son tan distintas que no se pueden hacer con `roles y permisos` es mejor con `API REST` pero si usan la misma `DB` no creo que sean muy distintas

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta, es interesante, pero de este modo la imagenes que lleva un articulo de blog creado con tinymce que hago con ellas, sigue trayendo rutas cortas

Comment: Además no se porque como uno tiene https y el otro no me da error de `net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` que opinas @manrrique meneses yaranga

Comment: es un servidor apache autofirmado, solo usa `http`, ya que el código no aceptó los certificados, cambia tambien las `url` en `tinyMCE` https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/url-handling/

Comment: No te logro entender como solucionar lo del `https' @manrrique meneses yaranga lo otro del tiny si que guarda las urls absolutas pero con el fallo que te comentaba arriba del ssl

Comment: no uses `https`, dejalo como `http`, es decir `http://dominio.imagen.com`, olvidate del `https`, mientras no tengas certificados comprados, y con servidor `backend` no es necesario el `https`

Comment: Hola @manrrique meneses yaranga el problema es que yo no le pongo el `https`, de echo si miras el código html pone http, es el navegado que se niega

Answer (score 0):

si no te entendi mal quieres guardar tus imagenes en alguna ruta tuya.

contolador donde guardas la imagen

```
if ($request->hasFile('urlfoto')) {
            $destination_path = 'public/images';
            $image = $request->file('urlfoto');
            $image_name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $path = $request->file('urlfoto')->storeAs($destination_path, $image_name);

            $input['urlfoto'] = $image_name;
        }
```

Y asi podrias llamar a la imagen en tu html

```
<img src="{{ asset('/storage/images/' .$VariableDeLaBDDondeSeGuardanTusRegistros->urlfoto ) }}" class="rounded mx-auto d-block" style=" width: 150px; height: 100px;">
```

Comment: Hola gracias @salva garcia no es guardar las imagenes en otra ruta, tengo dos app de laravel en un mismo servidor y quiero poder acceder a las imagenes de una a otra. En realidad una se encarga de back y el otro el front, entonces la del front tiene que coger las imagenes del back

Comment: a pues una disculpa amigo, no he trabajado con 2 sitios en un servidor, una disculpa